# Does ANSI support links on text?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

When I use a link in my terminal emulator (I am using Gnome Terminal), it's being highlighted as link and if I click it it is opened in the browser.

Is it possible to have a text (e.g. `Hello World`) and when I click it to open an url (e.g. `http://example.com`)?

Is it possible to do this with some ANSI black magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Those links are created by Gnome Terminal when it notices certain patterns in the terminal buffer - e.g. patterns for http:// or ftp:// etc URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by now, look for the `OSC 8` ANSI code. Here's the adoption matrix: https://github.com/Alhadis/OSC8-Adoption/